# Expand sibebar menu with a home button?

Tags: menu, sidebar

I need a way to user expand sidebar menu, but I can't remove the logo (links to home page) to put a sandwich button.

In the second screen I placed an arrow to the right when cursor is hovering the menu. I don't think that is the best solution because the user maybe hover the menu at the bottom part.

[image: Menu, menu with hover and expanded menu]

Answer (score 1):

How about putting the hamburger / sandwich icon at the top on the left, and the logo just underneath? (or vice versa)

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply expand on hover? That negates the problem of trying to find a place for a button by not needing a button.

Comment: If I do this, it need to close with mouse out. I dont want this menu to be so sensitive to open and close.